# Keep Windows application alive until process in stopped..C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a console application and I write to a file every 2 seconds. it works fine:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamWriter.Write(" File Write Operation Starts : ");
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine(" ===================================== \n");
        m_streamWriter.Flush();
        timer1 = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        m_streamWriter.Flush();
    }
```

But, I need this to be something that runs in the background without the command prompt appearing. So I changed the output type to "Windows Application". Now when I run it, it writes the first line to the file and then that's it. The program terminates after one iteration. The timer of course is terminated as well.

How do I keep my Windows Application alive until the process is manually stopped?

(Note) - I cannot do a windows service, and i do not know of any other .Net programs that can run in the background. If anyone knows of one, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console.Readline won't block your process from terminating.  In a windows application the Console.In is set to a NullStreamReader, which means calling Console.ReadLine will return immediately since the NullStreamReader implementation of ReadLine is simply "`return null`"

The implementation below terminates after it iterates 1000 times, but if you never signal the cancellation it will run indefinitely.

I'm sure better implementations exist, I just whipped this out off the top of my head.

There are many ways to structure this, here is one example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Program instance = new Program(cts);

            Task.Run(() => { instance.MyApp(); });

            while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            };



        }

        private CancellationTokenSource _cts = null;
        public Program(CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            this._cts = cts;
        }

        public void MyApp()
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\dummydata\test.txt"));
            fi.Directory.Create();
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 1000)
            {
                i++;
                File.AppendAllText(fi.FullName, i + "=" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
            this._cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is doing what I want it to, mostly. I want to write to the file constantly until the app is manually killed. This writes to the file just once. I'll see how I can tweak your code to do that.

Comment: Yeah it's just a template for you to start with.  Replace my MyApp code with whatever you want.  The main loop will keep the app running.

Comment: If you use the timer you'll probably want to place an infinite loop in the MyApp section as well.